# creating simple DVD structure?

Tags: ffmpeg, dvd, dvd-burning, cddvd

I'm trying to make a DVD builder using C# , and I know that DVD's have a specific structure which I tried to find and I couldn't see any thing helpful , however  , I found some half-completed posts about this structure , which indicate the following :

- all DVD videos must be in '.VOB' format
- all DVD Videos must be in a folder named "VIDEO_TS" and DVD audios in a folder named "AUDIO_TS"  (specifically)
- "VIDEO_T" and "AUDIO_TS" must be burned to a DVD disk that follows a special filesystem called [UDF][1]

My question is If I managed to convert my video to suitable ".VOB" format  , then I burn it to a disk after adding it to those folders , would it be playable in any DVD player ? I mean is this enough to have a simple DVD disk ,   and if it wouldn't .. what would be the simplest DVD structure I can make ( without menus and chapters and other extra stuff  ) ? any links related to DVD would be great

Comment: no, it won't work. a dvd is not just a bunch of .vob files. there's a lot more to it than that.

Comment: @MarcB can you give me some links to start from ? or can you be more specific about the reasons ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD

Comment: You need to get a hold of the DVD Specification in order to fully understand all the format's ins and outs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To manipulate DVDs discs effectively, you need to understand a little about the file structure. This file structure is the same for all commercial DVD movies or DVD Video discs of your own home movies. The main data files have a VOB extension, but there are various types of VOB files and other files as well.

VIDEO_TS.IFO. The 'Video [Title Set] Manager Information Set' is a configuration file that defines the disc structure and also includes region coding information.

VIDEO_TS.VOB. The 'Video [Title Set] Object file for VMG Menu', this file works like a bookmark to tell the player that it is the start of the disc.

VIDEO_TS.BUP. Backup file of the' Video Manager Information Set' (VIDEO_TS.IF0).

those three files must be exist with suitable file system  , otherwise it sure won't work as said in comments .

see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD#DVD_drives_and_players) and [this](http://club.myce.com/f62/tutorial-dvd-video-file-structure-77646/) ..